# DD-WRT new router firmware block ad serving hostnames

Tags: dns, dd-wrt, adblock

I found an excellent link of hosts serving ads and tracking cookies. I'd like to run a DNS server on my (newly reflashed) router running the DD-WRT firmware, and re-route all connections to any of [these](http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=hosts;showintro=0&useip=0.0.0.0) hostnames to `0.0.0.0`.

I see options for DNSMasq on the interface to my router, but I don't think it gives me the capability to enter specific DNS entries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about rerouting them to the default gateway. In theory, that would only send them back to you. You could use the list as suggested on the web page and make all those hosts appear as 127.0.0.0 which would effectively prevent them from sending you any data.

This can be done in DNSMasq: Services > Additional DNSMasq Options

```
address=/some.local.hostname/192.168.1.1
address=/another.local.hostname/192.168.1.2
addn-hosts=/some/file/somewhere
```

This info is from a [dd-wrt discussion](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=693664)